# For example an array like this one [mango, banana, apple, orange, pineapple] will produce an array like this [m, a, p, n, a]

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Please I need an assistance, please how to loop through an array indexes and increment the output by 1
I mean like to loop through an array indexes and for the first output of the index 0 will logout the first alphabet, and for the index 1 will log out the second alphabet
For example an array like this one [mango, banana, apple, orange, pineapple] will produce an array like this [m, a, p, n, a]
In javascript

I tried using for loop on the array and I'm just looping over the indexes not the indexes of the index

Comment: can you add your code as well

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.map(fn(element, index, array))`:

```js
const data = ["mango", "banana", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"].map((string, i) => string[i])

console.log(data)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but please what if i want to increment the indexes by 2. for example instead of logging out [m, a, p, n, a] the first index of the array will log out the first letter, while the second index will log out the third letter and the third index log out the fifth letter, and so on

Comment: `["mango", "banana", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"].map((string, i) => string[i + 2])`

Comment: please I have a calculator code, and I want to grab every value that it is clicked and push it in an array, the value after clicking an operator.
for example, if the user clicks 22+5+2.4+6+88, I want to push the values in array like this [22, 5, 2.4, 6, 88]
in javascript

I tried listening to every click on the operator and whenever its clicked then the value will be push into an array, but at the end I'm getting a repetition of the whole value.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myList = ["mango", "banana", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"];
const myNewList = myList.map((fruit, index) => fruit.charAt(index));
```

This will loop over your fruits, and create an array with the character at the index. However, this will break if the fruit's length is less than the index it is at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` to create new array and pass a function that returns the character at the current index in the item.

```js
const fruits = ["mango", "banana", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"];

const result = Array.from(fruits, (item, idx) => item[idx]);

console.log(result);
```